# Error when filling database with false data with faker in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, faker

I started a project with laravel 8, I was adjusting the seeders to generate fake data with faker in the database, I have a table with images which I generate random images with faker, my ImageFactory.php file is like this:

```
namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\Image;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class ImageFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Image::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'url' => 'posts/' . $this->faker->image('./public/storage/posts', 640, 480, null, false)
        ];
    }
}
```

when executing the command:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
```

generates this error in the console:

```
copy(https://via.placeholder.com/640x480.png/001144?text=corrupti): Failed to open stream: Connection timed out at vendor/fakerphp/faker/src/Faker/Provider/Image.php:121
```

Looking for a solution to this I found that in the `Image.php` file that generates error, after the line where `CURLOPT_FILE` is placed these two lines and the problem would be solved, so that it would look like this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); //aggregated line
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //aggregated line
$success = curl_exec($ch) && curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) === 200; existente
```

However this did not solve my problem and the error still persists, I am using laravel 8 and php 8.

## **Update**

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, running the command `curl -vo /dev/null "via.placeholder.com/640x480.png/001144?text=corrupti"` I got this:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 2600:3c00::f03c:91ff:fe60:d792...
* TCP_NODELAY set
*   Trying 45.33.24.119...
* TCP_NODELAY set
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to via.placeholder.com (45.33.24.119) port 80 (#0)
> GET /640x480.png/001144?text=corrupti HTTP/1.1
> Host: via.placeholder.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.6.2
< Date: Sat, 13 Feb 2021 14:36:37 GMT
< Content-Type: image/png
< Content-Length: 1558
< Last-Modified: Sat, 09 Jan 2021 14:00:02 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: "5ff9b6e2-616"
< Expires: Sat, 20 Feb 2021 14:36:37 GMT
< Cache-Control: max-age=604800
< X-Cache: L1
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
<
{ [1126 bytes data]
100  1558  100  1558    0     0   3386      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3386
* Connection #0 to host via.placeholder.com left intact
```

Comment: That dosen't look like a Laravel problem, maybe it's something with your connection, maybe it's something with your curl package, or OS.

Comment: Can you complement your question with the output of this command on the terminal: curl -vo /dev/null "https://via.placeholder.com/640x480.png/001144?text=corrupti"